# True and false statements with lists

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with determining whether or not a specific word lies in a list. For example, if I have the list `mylist=["This is a","test list that","serves as an example"]` and say I want to determine whether or not a specific word lies in a specific index of the list:

```
def test():
    if "This" in mylist[0] == True:
        print("In index")
    else:
        print("Not in index")
```

Obviously, the word "This" lies in `mylist[0]`, but whenever I run `test()`, it prints "Not in index". What is the error?

Comment: just drop the `== True`. I'd have to go back and look up the operation order, but it's possible that instead of `if ("This" in mylist[0]) == True` it's doing `if "This" in (mylist[0] == True)`. However I would expect that to throw a `TypeError`

Comment: My guess is that you don't need the `== True` part. `if x in y` is already valid and will show if it's in the list or not.

Comment: @AdamSmith that is an (valid) answer not a comment, isn't it ?

Comment: @SleepProgger yes, but a rather trivial one and not worthy of "Answer" status without a good deal more research being done. Doubly so because I anticipate the issue with the actual code isn't being faithfully reproduced here

Comment: @PeterWood good catch on the dupe!

Comment: @AdamSmith I asked it myself 2.5 years ago.